# Compile-time array constants

Tags: c++, templates, standards, compile-time-constant

I seem to be missing something rather fundamental.
I'm trying to use const array members at compile-time.

```
const int list[3] = { 2, 5, 7 };
const int a = list[2]; // this doesn't error?

template<int N1, int N2>
struct tmax {
  enum { value = ((N1 > N2) ? N1 : N2) };
};

const int b = tmax<2,4>::value;
const int c = tmax<list[0],list[1]>::value; // error is here

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp:10:24: error: 'list' cannot appear in a constant-expression
prog.cpp:10:30: error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Here is the [relevent IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/Iuk1r)

So why doesn't this work? What am I missing? What should I do differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just because an object is `const` doesn't mean it's a compile time constant expression.

```
main.cpp:10:20: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
const int c = tmax<list[0],list[1]>::value; // error is here
                   ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:20: note: read of non-constexpr variable 'list' is not allowed in a constant expression
main.cpp:1:11: note: declared here
const int list[3] = { 2, 5, 7 };
          ^
```

This is the reason for `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int list[3] = { 2, 5, 7 };

template<int N1, int N2>
struct tmax {
    enum { value = ((N1 > N2) ? N1 : N2) };
};

const int b = tmax<2,4>::value;
const int c = tmax<list[0],list[1]>::value; // works fine now
```

As for why this works:

```
const int a = list[2]; // this doesn't error?
```

initializing a `const` variable doesn't require a constant expression:

```
int foo(int n) {
    const int a = n; // initializing const var with a non-compile time constant
```

Comment: I'd figured constexpr would be helpful, and now that I look I see it has wider adoption than I'd thought. With that said, a bit more of an explanation as to why the declaration of const int a works but list[1] specifically doesn't would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: OK, so visual studio 2012 doesn't plan to support constexpr. Anyone got any other solutions? I don't HAVE to use it for this, but it would be nice.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave I added more of the compiler diagnostics which explains exactly why list[1] isn't a constant expression.

Answer (score 4):

Expressions are not *constant expressions* if they contain any one of a number of disallowed sub-expressions. One such class of disallowed sub-expressions is:

> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding
>       initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers
>       to a sub-object of such an object, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not
>       ended, initialized with a constant expression;

In particular, while the name of a const object of enum or intergral type initialized with a constant initializer forms a *constant expression* (reading its value is what causes the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion), sub-objects of an const aggregate object (such as `list` in your example, an array) do not, but would if declared `constexpr`.

```
const int list[3] = { 2, 5, 7 };
const int a = list[2];
```

This is valid but `a` does not constitute a *constant expression* because it is not initialized with a *constant expression*.

By changing the declaration of `list` (we don't have to change the declaration of `a`), we can make `a` form a constant expression.

```
constexpr int list[3] = { 2, 5, 7 };
const int a = list[2];
```

As `list[2]` is now a *constant expression*, `a` is now a `const` object of intergral type initialized with a *constant expression* so `a` can now be used as a constant expression.

Comment: It almost makes me cry that visual studio 2k12 isn't going to support constexpr. I've never used arrays like this in template metaprogramming but I was looking forward to it...